# Lumia black update for Lumia 520

Tags: wifi, lumia-black-update

I have no Wifi connection anywhere near my place. I'm not able to download the Black update because of this. Please could someone tell me how to update the phone without a Wifi connection?

Comment: Do you have an computer with an internet connection?

Comment: Yes I do have a computer with internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone has an Over-the-Air download size limit of 50 Mb. It applies for the Windows Phone Store for sure, but apparently also for updates.

Someone asked a similar question in [this Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/how-do-i-get-a-windows-8-update-on-phone-without/639282c9-166b-4c1c-8c18-c5139cdadc89?msgId=f7b55746-0475-4a38-bfcd-f06c5c373298) thread, and as you can see in the replies, you need Wifi.

If there's really no place where you can get Wifi nearby (cafe, fast-food, airport, other public place...), try asking a friend to set a wifi hotspot with is phone.